# How to information of user of devise such as user's address in registration place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How to add a field such as address and other information of user that created by devise in registration place?

By using another table? or set a attr in model?

I have look through the documentation and found nothing, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create separate models/migrations for additional fields and link them together (especially addresses go well in a model) or you add the fields to the devise migration directly. This is a devise migration I use for a small University project:

```
def self.up
  create_table(:students) do |t|
    t.database_authenticatable :null => false
    t.recoverable
    t.rememberable
    t.trackable
    # t.confirmable
    # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
    # t.token_authenticatable
    t.string :name
    t.string :studentNumber
    t.references :faculty
  t.timestamps
end
```

And the related line in the model:

```
attr_accessible :studentNumber, :email, :name, :faculty, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Comment: I think a separate model is the better way (with foreign key to the User model), since tomorrow if Devise is replaced with something else, not much needs to be changed (if at all)